# Customize popover bootstrap with Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have in my HTML a popover, and it's showing after a click. Here is my HTML

```
<div tabindex="0" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger order"
                     data-template="<div class='popover'><div class='arrow'></div><div class='popover-body'></div>"
                     role="button"
                     data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus"
                     data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?"
                     data-placement="left"
                     @click="addToCart">Add model
                </div>
```

I have a problem to customize popover width and height and element where I write text in this popover. I probably think that it is content? I want to my popover be wider and higher maybe about: width: 250 ox and height: 300px. How can I do this? Here is my Vue code:

```
 addToCart() {
            if (typeof(this.sizeChoose) === 'undefined') {

                $('.order').popover(
                    'show'
                )
            }
   }
```

Comment: I don't suppose you've tried `.popover {width: 250px; height: 300px}`?

Comment: Yes I tryed, It doesnt work

Comment: It looks like it doesn't see this class at all